# File `balance.sty' not found

Tags: packages

i recently installed texworks 2012 full version in ubuntu 12.04.
i am working in latexila.
when i am running a .tex file the following error occured-
File `balance.sty' not found.

can any one help me

Comment: Is it installed?  Try `locate balance.sty` or `kpsewhich balance.sty`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you tell us what you've already tried?

Answer (score 8):

`balance.sty` belongs to the `preprint` bundle.

In Ubuntu and Debian Linux, the repository package `texlive-latex-extra` (see [file list](https://packages.debian.org/de/wheezy/texlive-latex-extra)) contains the preprint bundle. So you can install it by

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

in a terminal window, or use your Ubuntu package manager for the installation.

CTAN writes about it:

> preprint – A bundle of packages provided "as is"
>
> The bun­dle com­prises:
>
> - **au­th­blk**, which per­mits foot­note style au­thor/af­fil­i­a­tion in­put in the \au­thor com­mand,
> - **bal­ance**, to bal­ance the end of \twocol­umn pages,
> - **fig­caps**, to send fig­ure cap­tions, etc., to end doc­u­ment,
> - **full­page**, to set nar­row page mar­gins and set a fixed page style, and
> - **sub­la­bel**, which per­mits coun­ters to be sub­num­bered.